# touchesBegan method is not being called

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I am trying to detect touches, but the touchesBegan method is not being called.

In my ViewController, I have added the touchesBegan method. My Nib files owner is set to the correct V.C. The Nib itself consists of the view, with a scroll view and a tab bar. Nested in the scroll view is an image view, which has user interaction enabled. What is precluding touches from being registered, or preventing my implementation of touchesBegan from being called?

I've scoured the Internet and Apple docs, and I can't see what I am doing wrong. Also, I'm not really sure what code I can post here to help with my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot more reading, I've now got a scrollview and a imageview, both of which are created programatically. The imageview is a sub view of the scrollview, and scrollview has been subclassed so that the touches ended method can decide whether it was a single touch, in which case call the touches ended method from the view controller, otherwise call its supers method. This works just fine, however, why is it that this cannot be done without subclassing scrollview? Is it my lack of understanding of how scrollview works, or is it just a limitation of it?